# Constrain associated type to generic class

Tags: swift, inheritance, protocols

I'm trying to make a protocol with an associated type which has an initializer that takes the class that conforms to the protocol as its argument type. This by itself works fine:

```
protocol A {
    associatedtype B: C where C.InitializableBy == Self
}

protocol C {
    associatedtype InitializableBy
    init(arg: InitializableBy)
}
```

However, since I don't want to write a new initializer for every class, I want the type constraint of `B` to be a class. I've tried this approach:

```
protocol A {
    associatedtype B: D<Self>
}

class D<T> {
    init(arg: T) { ... }
}
```

but this doesn't work, or at least I haven't been able to make a class conform to the protocol this way. The only way I've gotten it to work is by using both a class and a protocol:

```
protocol A {
    associatedtype B: C where C.InitializableBy == Self
}

protocol C {
    associatedtype InitializableBy
    init(arg: InitializableBy)
}

class D<T> : C {
    typealias InitializableBy = T
    init(arg: T) { ... }
}
```

This way a class can conform to `A` by having a nested type that implements `D` and doesn't have to redefine the initializer:

```
class Test: A {
    class B: D<Test> {}
}
```

But I would like to get around using the "dummy protocol" `C`, as it is not intented to be implemented by classes other than `D`.

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need.

```swift
protocol A {
    associatedtype B = D<Self>
}

class D<T> {
    init(arg: T) {}
}
```

or

```swift
protocol A {
    typealias B = D<Self>
}

class D<T> {
    init(arg: T) {}
}
```

The reason your code doesn't work as is is that `:` means 'conforms to' rather than 'is'. You are just meaning to give another name to D unless I am mistaken.